# AWS codecommit not able to clone repo completely

Tags: git, amazon-web-services, clone

[original image at the aws codecommit repo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hRPwT.png)

[image of the same file when cloned and opened in editor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VJdcg.png)

I cloned a repo from aws and when i opened the repo to check the file, the contents are missing from it. I've attached the screenshot of the original file and the same file after cloning it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure that you're at the same commit/branch as the AWS repo? Check using `git log`. A git repo can have multiple branches. Right after you clone the default branch will usually be "master". On your AWS screenshot you are showing the "dev" branch. To switch from "master" to "dev" use:

```
git checkout dev
```